# Using Siri to automatically add Outlook events to iCal Calendar

Tags: ms-office, calendar, siri, ical, google-calendar

**Context**

---

There is currently a feature for Apple Mail whereby you can enable Siri, such that it will automatically add any event/invitation picked up in Apple Mail to your iCal calendar. For example, should I receive an invite for an event on Thursday at 7 pm, it will add that to the calendar - like the below image, but automatic.

[image]

---

**Question**

---

Currently, I use both iCal Apple Calendar **and** Outlook for my events, which often come in through Outlook. I am aware that Outlook does have its own calendar, but I personally prefer the iCal calendar.

> **I am wondering if there is a way to add Siri to **Outlook** such that any invitation for a meeting/any event details found could be automatically added to my iCal calendar, rather than having to manually add it?**

---

**Post-Note**

---

I would prefer it if there were a way to do this without switching my Outlook and iCal mail accounts.
Perhaps a possible solution is to somehow sync the Outlook calendar to the iCal calendar?

---

***Thanks.***

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution to display all Outlook Calendar events in the Apple Calendar app.
(Is that what you want?, your question is mixing many things, I have solutions for each of them but what is your real need?)

I will provide screenshots but everything is in French, I hope you can locate things and/or use Google Translate ;)

1. Open https://outlook.live.com/calendar/0/view/month
   [image]
   See my calendar is empty I added a test event...

Go to settings like that :

3. Share/Publish the calendar
   [image]
4. Copy this link :
   [image]

Thanks to this link we can go to the Apple Calendar app and subscribe to it.

5. Open Calendar app and click to something like subscribe to a calendar :
   [image]
6. Paste the previous copied link
7. You can give it a name and a colour, set few settings.
   [image]
8. We are done !
   [image]

As you can see the test event appeared. From now everything that is added/modified/deleted in the Outlook Calendar will be updated and showed here in Apple Calendar app as read only.

P.S. click CMD+R to trigger a refresh of Apple Calendar if needed

### EDIT 1:

The solution above works for Outlook, but what if you directly have an **Exchange** account?
The solution is even better, you can directly add the account in the Apple Calendar app (Menu Calendar > Settings > Accounts. Then tap the add button (bottom left). And finish by login your Exchange account.)

[image]

Comment: This is wonderful. Thanks for carefully documenting what you learned. I’m trying to level up on the web versions of office - there is so much feature and complexity to discover. It’s fast, too...

Comment: Can you do this on an exchange account?

Comment: @Gill If you have an exchange account it is even better, you can directly add this account in the Apple Calendar app (Menu Calendar > Settings > Accounts. Then add button bottom left. Finish by login your Exchange account.)

Comment: Oh dear! Why didn't I think of that! Perfect, that is the solution. I suggest you add that as an edit to the bottom of your answer, and I'll award the bounty once you have done that @LorisFoe

Comment: @Gill Happy to hear that it helped you. I edited my answer too :)